# Return strings separated by line break in Rack application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a Sinatra application and a method

```
get '/page123' do
  "string1\nstring2"
end
```

If I go to `'/page123'`, I'll see only one string of `string1 string2` without line break between them.

How do I show them as

```
string1
string2
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `<br>` tag doesn't seem to work for you, try this:

```
get '/page123' do
  content_type 'text/plain'
  "string1\nstring2"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of your HTML, `string1 string2` will actually be `string1\nstring2`, but, as expected, the `\n` is a new-line and invisible except for its effect of making the line break and start a new one.

Browsers gloss over (AKA ignore) embedded carriage returns and, instead, only honor tags like `<p>` and `<br>`, unless the text is embedded inside `<pre>` blocks. Try copying the following into a text file and open it in your browser:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
string1
string2
</pre>
<p>string1<br>string2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

They'll both show the two words, on separate lines, in different fonts. Both are valid ways of forcing a line-break in HTML.

It'd be good for you to learn the ways that browsers display HTML. They don't treat it as text, because it isn't. HTML is a language which the browser interprets and uses the tags as instructions about how to present the text.